# Can't get git-tfs to clone for me

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

Trying to use git-tfs to clone a TFS directory I'm using this command:

```
C:>git-tfs clone http://xxxtfs10:8080/tfs $/Servers/YYYYYY mygit
```

I created mygit using:  git init mygit

I'm trying to get the directory at Servers/YYYYY in tfs. But consistently it tells me  the "Specified git repository directory is not empty".

I didn't try to put anything in it though, just did the init.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Is any part of it blatantly, obviously wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/clone.md):

> The clone command creates a new git repository, initialized from a TFS
>   source tree and fetch all the changesets

In other words, you shouldn't `init` the repository yourself first. Try cloning into a non-existing or empty directory.